# Traffic drops after changing to UK server

Tags: web-hosting, web-traffic

Because my website has some traffic, I moved it to other server (from US to UK). The UK server is Fasthosts.

But the traffic suddenly drops. [*edit: broken image removed.*]

Lots of my traffic comes from search engines.

All my websites (3 websites) hosted in this UK server get less traffic than in US. Ping from US gives great response.

What happened? Does search engine prioritizing US server more than UK?

Comment: The image does not really show a drop. It shows a drop RIGHT AFTER A GAIN - basically a spike, which can mean the reason or the spike just disappeared. Your 15 minutes of fame, so to say.

Answer (score 1):

When did you do the move? Has your DNS changed over completely? It's possible your site isn't coming up yet on all the DNS servers so your traffic is hitting a nonexistent server until everything migrates.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this SEOMoz article][1], as long as your domain name and hosting country stay the same, switching from one reliable host to another should have no SEO impact. *If you're changing your domain name and/**or hosting country**, that can definitely affect your ranking and is a much more complex issue.*